# Deterministic builds for Mono 3.2.8

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian, gmcs

We recently noticed that our C# application has a different checksum on every build, which I've discovered is due to the ECMA 335 Standard for the Common Language Infrastructure.

It seems to equate to these values being generated by the compiler:

```
// Time-date stamp:

// MVID:
```

Now we have tested building in mono 4 - which I've found has a "deterministic" mode enabled by default. But upgrading in the time frame I'm currently working too would be a worst case scenario.

My question is, are there any compile options I can use to force these values or stop them from being generated?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `which I've found has a "deterministic" mode enabled by default` -> share with us where you got that info from

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1297

Comment: you're linking a roslyn issue; Mono 3.x didn't embed roslyn (but had its own mono compiler, not MS compiler), so you definitely need to upgrade